# What is the 'predicate' in the sentence 'Frank has been studying syntax lately.'

Tags: syntactic-analysis, linguistics, predicate

Certainly the content verb is viewed as the (core of) the predicate. but I am curious about the auxiliary verbs. Should they be included in the main predicate? In other words, is the main predicate in the sentence above *has been studying* or just *studying* and why?

Comment: In a narrow sense, "study" is the underlying semantic predicate. All the rest is an aspectual specification.

Comment: The predicate is the verb phrase "has been studying syntax lately". "Has" functions as the predicator (head) of the VP. Note that the predicate consists of the predicator and two embedded subordinate clauses: has [been [studying syntax lately]].

Comment: Anything not the Subject is the Predicate. And the so-called auxiliary verbs provide needed information.

Comment: @BillJ I agree with you with respect to the fact that the predicate is the whole VP and I would like to add that "predicate" is not a syntactic notion anyway. However, there is no subordibation in the case you quote.

Comment: @Nico 'Predicate' is the standard syntactic term in English grammar. Of course there is subordination; I depicted the structure in my earlier comment.

Comment: @BillJ You mean dependency, maybe. Subordination only relates to clauses...

Comment: @Nico What are you talking about? The two bracketed elements **are** clauses: has [been [studying syntax lately]]. Thus, "been studying syntax lately" is a clause functioning as complement of "has", and "studying syntax lately" is a clause functioning as complement of "been".

Comment: @BillJ In syntactic terms your brackets refer to "dependency". Subordination relates to cases such as: "I didn't know that you were here", where "that you were here" functions as a subordinate of the main clause "I didn't know". This is the terminology used!

Comment: @Nico They are subordinate clauses functioning as catenative complements. Auxiliary verbs when used as markers of tense, aspect, mood, or voice are catenative verbs.

Comment: @BillJ Believe what you like!

Comment: @Nico I suggest you learn English grammar!

Comment: @BillJ I suggest you get familiar with syntactic terminology (1st term) and learn the difference between "clauses" and "dependency in (verbal) phrases", which is what you are writing about.

Comment: @Nico I'm well familiar with the terminology, thank you. I'm not talking about phrases, but clauses functioning as catenative complement of auxiliary verbs, which are catenative verbs. FYI, a verb phrase is 'head' of a clause, and it's the latter that is subordinate.

Comment: No, the counterpart of a "head" is not a "subordinate", but a "dependent".https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_(linguistics)

Comment: @Nico Incidentally, your continual arguing is no doubt confusing the OP.

Comment: @BillJ Who started arguing 3 hours ago? My remarks were finished yesterday...

Comment: @Nico You did in your second and subsequent comments, which I simply responded to. Have you considered the possibility that we are probably in different time zones?